# Can hypothesis be used to generate data of a specific type (ie. zip codes or phone numbers)?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-hypothesis

I am looking into using [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for some of my testing. I like that it can generate a large variety of data to find edge cases. However, I'd like to be able to tailor some of my tests just a bit more.

For example, I can define a test to generate [integers](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.integers), but I'm expecting this test to conform to valid zip codes are well. Can I do this? Or, perhaps, more complex conform to non-US zip codes, which are all integers, but others (say, Canada) are not?

The same type of thing would be useful for [text](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.text) fields that are expected to conform to some type of mask (ie. email address).

Right now I have test cases that are decorated like this:

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as st
@given(st.integers())
```

For this particular case, I'd like it to also conform to US zip code rules.

```
@given(st.text())
```

For this one I'd like it to generate patterns that are in an email-like format.

Can hypothesis do this type of generation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hypothesis can do more or less any kind of generation you like, but if there aren't built in strategies you need to write one yourself, usually using the @composite decorator. [Here's an article from the site on how to do this sort of thing](http://hypothesis.works/articles/generating-the-right-data/).

For the specific cases emails, there's [some ongoing work](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/pull/484) on providing a good builtin implementation but it probably won't arrive that soon.

I don't know of anything that does zip codes, and doing it properly looks hard, but looking at what other random generators do you can probably just get away with `st.integers(501, 99950).map(lambda i: "%05d" % (i,))`, which just takes an integer between 501 and 99950 inclusive and formats it as a 5 digit code.